# How do I go through a door opening?

Tags: warframe

Sometimes I have a bit of trouble going through door openings.

My problem is the lasers:
[image: Door opening with @Lazers]

I know some Warframes have abilities that let you pass through them and you can slide through them but that dose not always work.

What do I need to do to make sure I always succeed when trying to slide through?

or even better is there a trick to getting them to turn off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game looked fun and I wanted to read some info about how to begin and such. And I think I found your awnser in this guide: http://guidescroll.com/2013/04/warframe-essential-beginners-tips/

> Corpus Mission Tips
>
> If you find your way blocked by a Laser Barrier, there is most likely one or more security cameras around that detected a hostile target.
>
> Look for green (non hostile cameras) or red (hostile camera detecting your or your teammates) on the ceiling nearby and destroy them to shut down the barrier.
>
> Tiplet: if you cannot find the security camera, move the whole team somewhere to try to get out of the camera’s detection. Then either make a dash for it or try to deduce where the cameras are.
>
> Also, it is possible to bypass an active Laser Barrier by using some powers (from wiki: Excalibur‘s “Slash Dash,” Rhino‘s “Rhino Charge,” Loki‘s “Invisibility,” and Trinity‘s “Link“) or *sometimes* by sliding (though not very reliable for the beginner)

This is how it looks when it has not detected you:
[image]

When it has detected you it will glow red and follow your movement.

Comment: @Blem I guess you found the cameras? :) Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Yea, once i knew to look for it they where easy to spot since they light up the ceiling :)

Comment: Oh, and since Rhino's Ironskin ability blocks all knock back/ "knock down"(where you fall down and have to stand back up, not the same as bleed out), I have found that I can just walk through the barrier. It probably does a ton of damage to Ironskin, through (Ironskin runs out when it absorbs enough damage)

Answer (score 1):

Roll through it, but you still will take extremely minimal damage. Go right in front f it, then roll.

Comment: This is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I have with the dash-slide approach, is that often the gate is within a door, that will only open when you're close, and will block the slide from passing through, as the door slowly opens.

Another method that can help, is Volt's speed rush, which will almost always allow you to slide straight through.

Excal's Slashdash/SuperJump, Rhino's Charge, Loki's Switch Teleport/Invis, Ash's Teleport, Nova's Wormhole and Trinity's Link/Blessing should all be able to bypass the barrier.